# Facebook integration issue

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

Is is possible in iPhone application to get friends email id on Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't get friends' emails. Check out graph api permissions.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Answer (score 0):

NO, Its not possible to get email ids of friends although you can ger facebook ids of friends